# is there way to overcome this android studio error?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am having this error FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> 8 exceptions were raised by workers:
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10m 38s
8 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 7 up-to-date
```

Any solution for this? Because i have searched on google. No way.

Comment: Add more details related to code, scenario and other details

Answer (score 1):

If you have updated the Android studio to 3.4 or using Android Studio 3.4
there is issue with gradle version 
downgrade the gradle version work fine

**Change**

```
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4'
```

**to**

```
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
```

Comment: thanks MJM I think i upgrade gradle thanks alot i will downgrade it God bless you